# Adding Marker and displaying it on google map as soon as addmarker is called in a for loop

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a Android project where I need to plot markers on Google map V2.
I received the JSON response from server. I parse the received response in for loop. I call AddMarker for every iteration in post execute of async task. But all the markers are shown on the map only after the parsing is completed.
I want the marker to be reflected on the map as soon add marker for it is called.
Can someone please guide me to do this?
Thanks

Following is the post execute method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BusinessInfoArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject eachBusinessObject = BusinessInfoArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Pojo_business b = new Pojo_business();
        b.setBusinessProfileID(eachBusinessObject.getString("BusinessProfileID"));
        b.setBusName(eachBusinessObject.getString("BusName"));
        b.setAnnouncementMessage(eachBusinessObject.getString("AnnouncementMessage"));
        b.setLatitude(eachBusinessObject.getString("Latitude"));
        b.setLongitude(eachBusinessObject.getString("Longitude"));
        b.setBusinessMobileNo(eachBusinessObject.getString("BusinessMobileNo"));
        b.setBusinessImage(eachBusinessObject.getString("BusinessImage"));

        arrBusinessProfilesSearch.add(b);
        MarkerOptions mrkopt = new MarkerOptions();
        mrkopt.position(new LatLng(Double
                .parseDouble(b.getLatitude()), Double
                .parseDouble(b.getLongitude())));

        mrkopt.snippet("B" + b.getBusinessProfileID());

        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor;
        if (eachBusinessObject.getString("IsMoving").equals("true")) {
            bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.public_pinn_moving);
        } else {
            bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.public_pinn_fixed);
        }

        mrkopt.icon(bitmapDescriptor);
        mMap.addMarker(mrkopt);

    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielNugent : Please check. I have added PostExecute method of AsyncTask. I have removed some additional code that was present in it. As I wanted to show only the required part. So here at the end line there is mMap.addMarker(mrkopt);. I want the marker to appear on the map as soon this is called for that particular marker. Thanks

Comment: Actually I tested it with approx 2500 markers. The screen freezes for a while and then all markers appear suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

here you are doing bitmap process in for loop. 
so it's better to put outside of for loop and take 2 bitmap variable and assign these bitmap in for loop as per your condition.

like this

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorIsMovingTrue,bitmapDescriptorIsMovingFalse;

bitmapDescriptorIsMovingTrue = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.public_pinn_moving);

bitmapDescriptorIsMovingFalse= BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.public_pinn_fixed);
```

//inside for loop

```
for(..){
//your process
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor;
    if (eachBusinessObject.getString("IsMoving").equals("true")) {
        bitmapDescriptor = bitmapDescriptorIsMovingTrue;
    } else {
        bitmapDescriptor = bitmapDescriptorIsMovingFalse;
    }
}
```

this way i guess to much memory process reduce

and you can use clustering in google map [reference regarding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering) this

Comment: oh yes this will surely help to speed up the process. Thanks Sanket. But any idea about how i plot the markers one by one as the for loop proceeds.